# Java WS Client HTTPS transport via remote IIS server

Tags: java, https, iis-6, webservice-client

I've searched around so apologies if this is a repeat question:

A web service provider I work with has migrated to the cloud, requiring TLS connections.
My customer's (The web service consumer) java environment is setup with Tomcat acting as the container, connected via AJP to an IIS (v6) web server. The IIS server is where the Security is handled.

[Tomcat srv running WS Client] --AJP Connector--> [IIS server w/ SSL] ---> [Secure Web Service]

I'm trying to understand how to invoke the HTTPS connection from my app. From what I understand, the IIS server will create the HTTPS connection, but I don't have access to that certificate/keystore on the tomcat server (at least that's my understanding). Is there a way in java to invoke an HTTPS connection remotely so the IIS server can use it's certificate?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Have your client java app tried to establish a connection to your new destination server/endpoint? Did you get any errors?

Comment: @MauricioGuzinski I have repointed the client to the new endpoint. I confirmed from the SSL Debugging that the soap message is being built identically to the requests I can successfully make with soapUI.
I am trying to create the SSLContext for the HTTPS session. I am wondering if that's where my problem is since IIS supposedly handles the security? I'll check to see what the error I see is and reply.

Comment: @MauricioGuzinski sorry for the delayed reply. The web service client was not processing through the IIS, and the problem was in my code as I wasn't performing hostname validation. Thanks for the assistance and reply with this.